# Scrape a html page and store directly on Google Drive

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-drive-api

I have a script that I use to save web pages that I extract from the web. The script saves pages locally and works fine.

```
    def parse_page(self, link,q):
    response = requests.get(link, headers=self.headers,stream=True)
    print(f"\t- Response [{response.status_code}] for: {link}")
    published_date = self.get_date(response.text)
    if "text/html" in response.headers["content-type"]:
        format = ".html"
        data = response.text
        mode = "w"
    elif "application/pdf" in response.headers["content-type"]:
        format = ".pdf"
        data = response.content
        mode = "wb"
    elif "officedocument.word" in response.headers["content-type"]:
        format = ".docx"
        data = response
        mode = "wb"
    folder = urlparse(link).netloc
    filename = urlparse(link).path.split("/")[-1].replace("\n","")
    if filename == '':
        filename = folder+datetime.now().strftime("_%H_%M_%S")
    # Linux
    #path = self.root_folder+"/"+folder+"/"+filename+format
    # Win
    path =self.root_folder+"\\"+folder+"\\"+filename+format
    with self.safe_open_w(path, mode) as f:
        if format == '.docx':
            for chunk in data.iter_content(16*1024):  # 2 MB chunks
                f.write(chunk)
        else:
            f.write(data)
```

Now I want to save web pages directly to google drive. How can I directly save the data stream on Google Drive without first saving the file locally?

To upload files on Google Drive I have used this script:

```
try:
    # Call the Drive v3 API
file_metadata = {'name': 'file.jpg',
                 }
    media = MediaFileUpload('file.jpg',
                                mimetype='image/jpeg')
        # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media,
                                      fields='id').execute()
    print(F'File ID: {file.get("id")}')

except HttpError as error:
    print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
    file = None
```

except Exception as e:
print(e)

But now I want to upload the data stream (response, response.text, response.content) directly, without storing the file locally.
How I cant reach that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Google Drive API, uploading data in memory rather then file on disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61348838/python-google-drive-api-uploading-data-in-memory-rather-then-file-on-disk)

Answer (score 0):

https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.MediaIoBaseUpload-class.html

Use `MediaIoBaseUpload` and `io.ByteIO` class.